# How to fuzzy query against multiple fields in elasticsearch?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

Here's my query as it stands:

```
"query":{
    "fuzzy":{
        "author":{
            "value":query,
            "fuzziness":2
        },
        "career_title":{
            "value":query,
            "fuzziness":2
        }
    }
}
```

This is part of a callback in Node.js.  `Query` (which is being plugged in as a value to compare against) is set earlier in the function.

What I need it to be able to do is to check both the `author` and the `career_title` of a document, fuzzily, and return any documents that match in either field.  The above statement never returns anything, and whenever I try to access the object it should create, it says it's undefined.  I understand that I could write two queries, one to check each field, then sort the results by score, but I feel like searching every object for one field twice will be slower than searching every object for two fields once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-match-query.html

If you see here, in a multi match query you can specify the fuzziness...

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "fields":  [ "text", "title" ],
      "query":     "SURPRIZE ME!",
      "fuzziness": "AUTO"
    }
  }
}
```

Somewhat like this.. Hope this helps.